# How do left join retrive data when there two conditions?

Tags: mysql, join

If there is query as follows:

```
SELECT Name, RollID, Score 
FROM StudentTable 
LEFT JOIN ScoreTable ON (StudentTable.ID = ScoreTable.StudentID 
AND StudentTable.SubjectCode = ScoreTable.CorseCode);
```

1. Will the LEFT JOIN applied after the condition `"(StudentTable.ID = ScoreTable.StudentID AND StudentTable.SubjectCode = ScoreTable.CorseCode)"` is calculated or
2. will it LEFT JOIN with individual condition first and later AND the result?

What will be the difference between 1 and 2?

Comment: The `ON` clause is evaluated **during** the `LEFT JOIN` execution. That is the meaning of any JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `JOIN` (no matter its type) without an (implicit or explicit) `ON` clause combines each row from the left table with each row from the right table.

When the `ON` clause is present (*see the update below*), only the rows from both tables that match the `ON` conditions are combined and go to the next step.

A `LEFT` join makes sure all the rows from the left table are pushed to the next step, no matter if they have matches on the right table or not. If a row from the left table does not have a match on the right table (that verifies the `ON` conditions) then a row full of `NULL` values is used for the right table instead.

The `ON` conditions are applied at the `JOIN` step. The theoretical model starts by joining the tables (using the `ON` conditions for each `JOIN`) then it continues with the evaluation of the `WHERE` clause and so on.

In practice, for performance reasons, some database engines (and MySQL is one of them) push this model further and evaluate the `ON` clause together with the `WHERE` conditions that can be evaluated when the `ON` clause is evaluated. They basically move the evaluation of the `WHERE` conditions as early as possible in the processing chain in order to avoid wasting resources processing a row that won't be present in the result set.

Your question is not quite clear but the correct option is 1. The `ON` conditions are evaluated when the tables are `JOIN`ed.

---

#### Update:

As @onedaywhen notices in a comment, the first sentence of the original answer was not true for `NATURAL JOIN` and when the `USING` clause was used instead of `ON`.

The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) reads:

> The `NATURAL [LEFT] JOIN` of two tables is defined to be semantically equivalent to an `INNER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN` with a `USING` clause that names all columns that exist in both tables.

And also:

> The `USING(column_list)` clause names a list of columns that must exist in both tables. If tables `a` and `b` both contain columns `c1`, `c2`, and `c3`, the following join compares corresponding columns from the two tables:
>
> `a LEFT JOIN b USING (c1,c2,c3)`

The fragment expressed in the quote above is (from the join point of view) identical with:

```
a LEFT JOIN b ON a.c1 = b.c1 AND a.c2 = b.c2 AND a.c3 = b.c3
```

The bottom line is: sometimes the `ON` clause does not appear explicitly in the query but it is still present: `NATURAL JOIN` includes an implicit `USING`; `USING` is a special kind of `ON`. When such an implicit or explicit `ON` clause is present it is used to filter out the rows while the `JOIN` clause is processed, not after that.

Comment: LEFT JOIN ScoreTable ON (StudentTable.ID = ScoreTable.StudentID 
AND StudentTable.SubjectCode = ScoreTable.CorseCode) Will these be evluated as LEFT JOIN ScoreTable ON (StudentTable.ID = ScoreTable.StudentID) AND LEFT JOIN ScoreTable ON (Student Table. SubjectCode = ScoreTable.CorseCode)

Comment: No. The tables are joined only once but the combined rows must match both conditions in order to be used for further processing (`WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` etc).

Comment: The second fragment you suggested is not valid SQL. It becomes valid if you remove the `AND` and provide different aliases for the two instances of `ScoreTable`. It produces in the result set rows that contain the columns of `ScoreTable` twice, once from each of the joined instance. The first `StudentID` column (the one from the first `ScoreTable`) is equal to `StudentTable.ID`. The second `SubjectCode` (from the second instance of `ScoreTable`) is equal to `StudentTable.CourseCode`). The original query produces a result set whose rows contains the columns of `ScoreTable` only once.

Comment: I don't think your first sentence is a true statement for mySQL e.g. natural join. I'm almost sure it is not a true statement for SQL generally.

Comment: @onedaywhen hmm... you are right. `NATURAL JOIN` does not require an `ON` clause because it includes an implicit `USING` (which is short form of `ON`). I will reformulate.